# Serializing a FlowDocument from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, serialization, json.net, flowdocument

I have a C# WPF app in which I have a backgroundworker thread that periodically serializes the current working set of application data to file (using json.net).  One piece of data that's being serialized is a FlowDocument.  Serializing this from the main thread works fine, using the following Json.Net JsonConverter:

```
public class FlowDocumentSerializerJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
      writer.WriteValue(XamlWriter.Save((FlowDocument)value));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      ...
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
      return typeof(FlowDocumentSerializer).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
```

}

However, in my backgroundworker thread, at the line:

```
writer.WriteValue(XamlWriter.Save((FlowDocument)value));
```

I get a `System.InvalidOperationException`, saying:  "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Any ideas on how to work around this and still retain my auto-save feature?  I would prefer to keep the work in another thread, since I don't want to affect the user's experience when the auto-save occurs.

Comment: I don't think you can do this -- the user could be editing the `FlowDocument` in the main thread while the background thread is saving it, causing undefined behavior in the background thread.  Instead you may need to [save to an in-memory `XamlPackage`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/58a68465-7e90-452f-8296-5cad9445e116/saving-and-loading-richtextbox-content) in the UI thread, then write it to disk in the background.

Comment: By the way, `XamlWriter` [doesn't save embedded images](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b256eade-71b6-4bd7-bae5-43cd82e958e8/xamlwritersave-serialization-of-pasted-image-?forum=wpf).

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing with no luck. I need to load a bunch of XML files to different flow documents and then export them to PDF without affecting my UI thread. Getting the same error and can't really find anything related to this issue...